# Async await code does not running the same way with forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

I have this code, which when I run will run 'one' and 'two' in that order.

So the code below works fine.

```
(async () => {

  await runit('one').then(res => {
    console.info(res);
  });

  await runit('two').then(res => {
    console.info(res);
  });

})();
```

Now, I wanted to do the same thing but in a loop instead, so I've done this:

```
const arr = ['one', 'two'];
  arr.forEach(element => {
    (async () => {
      await runit(element).then(res => {
      console.info(res);
    });
  })();
});
```

Although is seems like the same code it's no longer running in the order that the code at the top is.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your first example is more like (in a simplified manner): `runit('one').then(() => runit('two))`

Comment: Here's a solution that uses a basic `for` loop: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/a7htxg3y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't wait because the function you execute is async, you are actually telling it not to wait. To fix it you could do simple for cycle:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const item = arr[i];
  await runit(item).then(res => {
    console.info(res);
  });
}
```

or you could use map and Promise.all:

```
const promises = arr.map(item => runit(item)));
const values = Promise.all(promises);
values.forEach(res => console.info(res))
```

The latter is preferred.

Comment: The latter runs things in parallel, while the former does not.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same things using `promise.all` function like below.

```
const arr = ['one', 'two'];
const promises = [];
  arr.forEach(element => {
      promises.push(runit(element));
  });

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    console.log(results)//you will get results here.
});
```

Comment: although good in some cases, this doesn't guarantee that promises will be resolved in chronological order (first one resolved, then second...)

Comment: `runit()` obviously returns a `Promise`. What would be the reason to pass this promise to `Promise.resolve()`?

Comment: It will resolve exactly the same order as an array index. I mean the resolved value will be received on the same index of promise.

Comment: @Andreas to make collection of promise. So that we can resolve all promises in single shot using `promise.all()`.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, Promise.resolve is completely redundant.

Comment: @narayansharma91 runit already returns a Promise, no need to resolve it one more time for no reason.

Comment: _"The `Promise.resolve()` method returns a `Promise` object that is resolved with a given value. **If the value is a promise, that promise is returned**;"_ Hence... `const x = runit('one'); Promise.resolve(x) === x /* true */` (Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), [ECMAScript 2015, 6th Edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve))

Comment: This answer runs things in parallel, which is not *"the same thing but in a loop"* from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `forEach` with `await`. It won't work right.

`forEach` ignores all results from the callback function it takes. If you pass it an `async` function—or any other function returning a promise—all promises returned will go unhandled.

Use native for-loops instead.
To match your non-looping code which only runs one item at a time, do:

```
for (const element of ['one', 'two']) {
  console.log(await runit(element));
}
```

This is substantially different from the other answers with `Promise.all`. `Promise.all` waits for wholesale completion of multiple promises, which implies things are running in parallel already.

To run things in parallel, do:

```
for (const res of await Promise.all(['one', 'two'].map(runit)) {
  console.log(res);
}
```